# Unable to install php5-tidy on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, debian

I am aware of the `php-tidy` package but I need to install `php5-tidy`. Debian repo listed here https://packages.debian.org/sid/arm64/php5-tidy/download is already in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and I have already run `sudo apt update`. Could you help?

```
sudo apt-get install php5-tidy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-tidy
```

Comment: Don't know which version of php is installed but run this command from terminal to see php packages with that name `apt search php.*tidy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think this command `apt search php.*tidy` would be more helpful in identifying the correct package name. So run that and pick from the results to install.

Comment: You saved the day! Thank you. I selected the following from the search results `php5.6-tidy/xenial 5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64`